# Как отправить полученный файл на другой сервер?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.7

Есть следующая система.

Существует сервер обработки *фото* на одном сервере и есть *основной сервер*.

Пользователь отправляет форму, в которой есть *фото*, на сервер обработки фото, сервер фото обрабатывает его и отправляет на основной сервер через *requests.post*. На данный момент работает, только если сначала сохранить файл на физический диск, а потом уже отправить его с (указанием пути) на основной сервер.

Как можно отправить файл через *requests.post*, не сохраняя его на диск?

Пробовал конвертировать с помощью **StringIO**, **BytesIO**, но так ничего и не вышло.

сохраняю на данный момент так:

```
# Получаю и сохраняю фото
f = request.FILES['photo']
f.save(file_path)

# Меняю размер фото
image = Image.open(file_path)
image.thumbnail([150, 150], Image.ANTIALIAS) 
image.save(file_path, image.format, quality=100, optimize=1)

# Отправляю так
fil = open(file_path, 'rb')
filess = {'photo': ('photo.jpg', fil, 'image/jpeg')}
request = requests.post("%s%s" % (domen, url), data=post, files=filess)
```

Собственно нужно отправить уже измененный файл image

На счет вывода тут ошибок не уверен что получится, пробовал разные варианты и много и ошибки в некоторых случаях не выходили, но на основном сервере файл не сохранялся, значит что то не то отправлял, на основном сервере нет возможности посмотреть логи ошибок.

То что я находил по отправке файла через **StringIO** ничего не работало, то сам модуль ругался что данные не те, то модель по отправке ругался что данные не те, поэтому причина видимо в том что я файл не правильно преобразовывал в **StringIO**. Видимо мой вопрос сводится к тому как правильно преобразовать этот файл к такому формату и потом как эти данные отправить через *requests.post*

Comment: Необходимы кусок кода, где Вы отправляете файл на другой сервер, и логи выводимых им ошибок.

Comment: Python какой версии?

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev Python2.7, но часть проектов переводится на 3 версию, если есть отличия в решении, то было бы очень хорошо увидеть вариант и для Python3, так как потом придется это все переделывать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Основной сервер-то как принимает картинку? Тоже как загружаемый файл? Тогда предельно просто:

```
def upload_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            f = request.FILES['photo']
            requests.post('http://example.com', files={f.name: f})
            return redirect('upload:success')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Если он ожидает поток байт в теле запроса, то чуть сложнее:

```
def upload_bridge(f):
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        yield chunk

def upload_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            requests.post('http://example.com',
                data=upload_bridge(request.FILES['photo']))
            return redirect('upload:success')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Только учтите, что большой файл может надолго поставить обработчик колом. Это может привести либо к обрыву соединения по таймауту, либо исчерпанию обработчиков и последующей недоступности сайта.

**UPDATE:**

```
from StringIO import StringIO

f = request.FILES['photo']

input = StringIO(f.read())
output = StringIO()

image = Image.open(input)
image.thumbnail([150, 150], Image.ANTIALIAS) 
image.save(output, 'PNG')

requests.post('http://example.com', files={f.name: output})

output.close()
input.close()
```

Этот вариант не только будет обработчик ставить колом, но ещё и память жрать будет.

Comment: Да, первый вариант подходит. Именно так я получаю файл, но, есть нюанс. Только сейчас я делаю сохранение а потом делается такой код 
    image = Image.open(file_path)
    image.thumbnail([image_x, image_y], Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image.save(file_path, image.format, quality=100, optimize=1)
вот именно последний вариант надо сохранить

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, отметьте его как решение.

Comment: Отредактировал свой вопрос, более точно описал что необходимо.